# how to fix User validation failed: username: Path `username` is required., number: Path `number` is required., email: Path `email` is required

Tags: reactjs

i am creating a new user and checking it exist in MongoDB database or not
=> below code is signup controller code
`

```
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
const User = require("../model/user.model");

const singupHandler = async (req, res) => {
    try{
       // console.log("Request Body:", req.body);
        const newUser = new User({
            username: req.body.username,
            number: req.body.number,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(req.body.password, process.env.PASSWORD_SECRET_KEY).toString()
        });
        const savedUser = await newUser.save();
        res.status(201).json(savedUser);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Error creating a user" })
    }
}

module.exports = singupHandler;
```

`

=>below code is usermodule.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
      username:{type: String,required: true},
      number:{type: Number,required: true,uniquie: true},
      email:{type: String,required: true,uniquie: true},
      password:{type: String,required: true},

})

const User=mongoose.model("User",userSchema);

module.exports= User;
```

am getting error like this

Error: User validation failed: username: Path `username` is required., number: Path `number` is required., email: Path `email` is required.
at ValidationError.inspect (D:\TTT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:50:26)
at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:805:19)
at inspect (node:internal/util/inspect:364:10)
at formatWithOptionsInternal (node:internal/util/inspect:2298:40)
at formatWithOptions (node:internal/util/inspect:2160:10)
at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:342:14)
at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:379:61)
at singupHandler (D:\TTT\controllers\signupController.js:16:17)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
errors: {
username: ValidatorError: Path `username` is required.
at validate (D:\TTT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1365:13)
at SchemaType.doValidate (D:\TTT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1349:7)
at D:\TTT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2972:18
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
properties: [Object],
kind: 'required',
path: 'username',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose#validatorError)]: true
},
number: ValidatorError: Path `number` is required.
at validate (D:\TTT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1365:13)
at SchemaType.doValidate (D:\TTT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1349:7)
at D:\TTT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2972:18
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
properties: [Object],
kind: 'required',
path: 'number',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose#validatorError)]: true
},
email: ValidatorError: Path `email` is required.
at validate (D:\TTT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1365:13)
at SchemaType.doValidate (D:\TTT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schemaType.js:1349:7)
at D:\TTT\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2972:18
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
properties: [Object],
kind: 'required',
path: 'email',
value: undefined,
reason: undefined,
[Symbol(mongoose#validatorError)]: true
}
},
_message: 'User validation failed'
}

Answer (score 3):

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: { type: String, required: true },
number: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },  // Fix typo here
email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },   // Fix typo here
password: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

And make sure you have that required fields (console log your fields in front to check) when creating a new user instance, and the issue should be resolved.